# What are the limitations of using backtick enclosed string with variables in it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently found out, that it's possible to use code like this (notice the backtick, instead of quote):

```
var test = '123';
var x = `test: ${test}`; // => test: 123
```

I don't quite know how to search this, so since i only seen people use this:

```
var test = '123';
var x = 'test: ' + test; // => test: 123
```

I haven't seen people use this, so i wanted to know, what are the drawbacks?
Cos this seems like cleaner way to write strings with variables in them.. I mean, in this example it might seem a bit silly, but if you have long string with multiple repeating variables, then this is much more readable, than using `+` all the time.

EDIT: This question has been marked as duplicate, but i don't see answer to my question.. I'm not asking, whats the difference. I'm asking what are the drawbacks of using this in all my code in the future. Are there javascript or browser version support, i have to worry about?

Comment: Its called template literal.

Comment: The ` character is a backtick. The ~ character is a tilde.

Comment: @JonasWilms there ARE drawbacks.. Check the accepted answer. This is why i asked

Comment: I'm sorry, why do you commend and mark my question as duplicate, if you also post stuff like "Too Long Didn't Read".. That's not how this site should be used.. If you can't be bothered to read my question, don't answer to it, especially if your answers are incorrect and misinformed..

Comment: @JonasWilms deleted your comment, nice.. gj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you’re talking about two separate things: concatenation of strings and ES6 template literals.

You already understand string concatenation, but template literals come with many other features, like tagged templates.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates

The one downside to template literals is that you may be writing for an older browser that doesn’t support them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i wanted to know.

Comment: It’s my pleasure.